# Uploaded images are not found in folder asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a upload function where it displays the uploaded image in a grdiview after the upload click.
Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/Uploads/" + fileName));
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
}
```

}

This works fine. It uploads and shows in the gridview. The problem I have is that the pictures are not directed to the path. Its not in the `uploads` folder.
Any tricks on this?

UPDATE
Show all in solution explorer and i got this:

[image]

Comment: Enable 'Show All files' in solution explorer and check App_Data > Uploads

Comment: did see it. please see updated. @Sanket

Comment: Right click on the uploads folder and select "Open Folder in File Explorer" and then it will show you all the images in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

On possible solution could be, when saving/uploading files, use Path.Combine

```
  FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs( Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"),fileName))
```

and similarly for:

```
files.Add(new ListItem(fileName,Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"),fileName)));
```

Comment: same thing happens sir

Comment: Another option:

files.Add(new ListItem(fileName,Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"),fileName)));

Answer (score 0):

Mostly i used following approach.

you can get help from following example code...

```
 string fnam, newname,ext, serpath,dbpath="", fid;
 ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(File_Upload.PostedFile.FileName);
 fnam = File_Upload.PostedFile.FileName;
 fid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 newname = fid + ext;
 serpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("uploads\\"), newname);
 dbpath = "~\\uploads\\" + newname;
 File_Upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(serpath);
```